# Query the account records near to 50kms radius

Tags: apex, soql

My current location is stored in currentPosition variable in terms of latitude and longitude.

```
public String currentPosition{get;set;}////37.77493,-122.419416
```

I have enabled Geolocation codes for Account billing Address feature to get the Account address in terms of latitude and longitude(BillingLatitude,BillingLongitude)

How to Query the account records near to me in 50kms radius using BillingLatitude&BillingLongitude?
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You will need this:

```sql
SELECT
    Account_Address
FROM
    Your_Account_Table
WHERE
    ROUND(ROUND(geography::Point(CurrentPositionLatitude, CurrentPositionLongitude, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point(BillingLatitude, BillingLongitude, 4326)), 2)/1609.344, 2) < 50
```

Comment: It measures the distance in miles though

Comment: From review: Adding a bit more details and an explanation on how this solves the problem might help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the GEOLOCATION and DISTANCE filters, outlined [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_geolocate.htm):

```
String[] parts = currentPosition.split(',');
Decimal latitude = Decimal.valueOf(parts[0]), longitude = Decimal.valueOf(parts[1]);
Account[] results = [
    SELECT Name FROM Account 
    WHERE DISTANCE(BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION(:latitude, :longitude), 'km') < 50];
```

I don't have any good data to test with, but this should get you started.

Comment: unexpected syntax: 'missing RPAREN at ',''

Comment: expecting a right parentheses, found ','

Comment: Hi, I am getting the above two errors when i am trying to execute the above query

Comment: @MaheshM Yes, there was a missing ")". I added it into the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below link, which describes solution to your requirement in a very precise way, and it can help with other things you might need as you are playing with Location.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_geolocate.htm